# Chrome Android React keyboard disappear when click on input

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome

So I have my site - deleted - and when I click on an input from an Android device from newer generations with Android 9 or 8( Samsung 
S9 or S8, Huaweii P9, ...) the keyboard appear but then immediately disappear.
The code would be this:

```
import React from "react";
import immer from "immer";

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.userRef = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            user: "",
            pass: ""
        };
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <h1 key="title">Panoro</h1>,
            <form 
                key="form"
                id="loginForm" 
                onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); setTimeout(this.onFormSubmit, 200); }} 
                autoComplete="new-password"
            >
                <input 
                    key="userInput" 
                    ref={this.userRef} 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={this.state.user}
                    onChange={(e) => { 
                        this.setState(immer(this.state, draftState => {
                            draftState.user = e.target.value;
                        })); 
                    }} 
                    required
                />
                <input 
                    key="passInput" 
                    type="password" 
                    placeholder="Parola" 
                    value={this.state.pass} 
                    onChange={(e) => { 
                        this.setState(immer(this.state, draftState => {
                            draftState.pass = e.target.value; 
                        }));
                    }} 
                    required
                />
                <button type="submit">{(this.isInvite) ? "Inregistrare" : "Login"}</button>
            </form>
        ];
    }
}
```